# addSubview does not make UISegmentedControl show up

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I am reading Chapter 15 of "Beginning iOS 5 Development" by Mark, Nutting, and LaMarche (Apress 2011). On page 556, I am supposed to show the segmented control from code, instead of dragging an object to nib from library. The code snippet is
... ...

```
self.smileyView.image = self.smiley;

self.segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"One", @"Two", @"Three", @"Four", nil]];
self.segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x + 20, CGRectGetMaxY(bounds) - 50, bounds.size.width - 40, 30);

[self.view addSubview:self.segmentedControl];

[self.view addSubview:self.smileyView];
[self.view addSubview:self.label];
```

... ...

Note that the smiley thing and label show up as expected, but the segmented control does not. BTW, I have duly declared the property segmentedControl in .h and synthesized it in .m .
Why am I not seeing this segmentedControl show up in iOS 6 simulator?

Comment: Where is this being called from? viewDidLoad?  Has bounds been declared?

Comment: Have you NSLogged to check the frame and bounds?

Comment: Yes, inside viewDidLoad, and     CGRect bounds = self.view.bounds;

Comment: The solution is to change "CGRectGetMaxY(bounds) - 50" to "CGRectGetMaxY(bounds) - 150". I wonder if this is a case of typo or misprint, or a case of not configuring the main view correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be mostly because the frame for the segmented control is not right.

After the add subview line place an NSLog as follows to see where is it in the screen and the size of it

```
  NSLog(@"frame %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.segmentedControl.frame))
```

And as a last effort try bringing the segmented control to the front.

[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.segmentedControl]

This should give you an idea of what is wrong

Comment: frame {{20, 498}, {280, 30}}
is the NSLog print-out

Comment: After I change the frame setting to    "self.segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x + 20, CGRectGetMaxY(bounds) - 150, bounds.size.width - 40, 30);" , the segmentedControl shows up! The change is change 50 to 150 when setting the Y origin relative to MaxY(bounds). Thank you guys!